# SyntaxError (Python): 'await' outside async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to write a bot for Discord but I keep getting an error message:

File "bot.py", line 33
await member.create_dm()
^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function

I am trying to get the bot to send a DM to a person who has just joined the server.

```
@client.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    member.dm_channel.send("Hi and welcome!")
```

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to define it as `async def` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```py
@client.event
@asyncio.coroutine
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    member.dm_channel.send("Hi and welcome!")
```

add `async` before `def`

for more information about async in python consider reading this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html